# A problem about splitting field and irreducibility of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Suppose that $K$ is the splitting field of $f(x)\in F[x]$, when the degree of $f(x)$ is $n$ and $[K:F]=n!$. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

i know that $K|F$ is normal,but i don't know how to approach this problem.

any hint is welcomed!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(x)$ were a product of two polynomials, say of degree $\ell$ and $n-\ell$, $0<\ell<n$, show that the splitting field would be of degree $\le \ell!(n-\ell)!$ over $F$.

Comment: can u pls expliane a little how?

Comment: Are you familiar with the argument showing that the splitting field of a polynomial of degree $m$ has degree at most $m!$? Use that for both factors.

Comment: no why it is true?pls write it as an answer,assuming this then the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

**A method if you know some Galois theory**:

First, prove that that the Galois group of a polynomial acts transitively on the roots of that polynomial if and only if the polynomial is irreducible.

Since $K$ is a splitting field, then $|\operatorname{Gal}(f)| = [K:F] = n!$.  Further, it is a fact that $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ can be thought of as a subgroup of $S_n$, so it must be the case that $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong S_n$.

Since $f$ has $\deg(f) = n$ roots (counting multiplicities), then $S_n$ must act transitively on them.

---

**A more direct method**:

Suppose $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ where $\deg(g) + \deg(h) = n$.

Then first construct a splitting field for $g(x)$ by adjoining roots:

$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1, \alpha_2] \subset ... \subset \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k]$$

Worst case scenario, you will need to adjoin $\deg(g)$ roots in total, in which a single linear factor breaks off of $g$ in each subsequent extension.  So what is the maximum possible degree of the corresponding splitting field for $g$?

Again, worst case scenario, $h$ is irreducible in $g$'s splitting field, so continue the above process, adjoining roots until it has split completely.  You will have to adjoin at most $\deg(h)$ more roots.

So in the splitting field of $f$, what is the maximum possible degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Kaj Hansen thanks but i'm not familiar with Galios theory.

Comment: pls see this with bounties too:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993666/a-problem-about-normal-extensions-polynomials

Comment: @user115608, I edited my response with a more direct method.